Как убрать анимацию при первом рендере?
Написал хук для анимации, но хочу убрать анимацию при первом рендере. Проблема в том, что анимации вообще нет, даже на втором рендере. Что не так? Если убрать проверку на первый рендер и по умолчанию добавить в стейт класс animate, то все нормально работает, но работает и с первым рендером.
export const useAnimateRoute = () => { 
    const [animationClass, setAnimationClass] = useState(''); 
    const isFirstRender = useRef(true); 
    const location = useLocation(); 
 
    useEffect(() => { 
        if (isFirstRender.current) { 
            isFirstRender.current = false; 
            return; 
        } 
 
        setAnimationClass('animate'); 
 
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => { 
            setAnimationClass(''); 
        }, 200); 
 
        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId); 
    }, [location]) 
 
    return animationClass; 
}

App.js
<BrowserRouter> 
      <Routes> 
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} /> 
        <Route path="/test/test2" element={<Test />} /> 
      </Routes> 
    </BrowserRouter>

Home.jsx, Test.jsx
const Home = () => { 
    const animationClass = useAnimateRoute(); 
 
    return ( 
        <div className={animationClass}> 
             <Link to='/test/test2'>123</Link>
        </div> 
    ) 
}

const Test = () => { 
    const animationClass = useAnimateRoute(); 
 
    return ( 
        <div className={animationClass}> 
            <h1>123</h1> 
        </div> 
    ) 
}


Зачем вам там useRef? Используйте обычный стейт useState(true)

Этот никак не решает задачу )

Ну возможно у вас проверка неправильная. должно быть if (!isFirstRender) return;

Вы вопрос читали хотя-бы?) мне наоборот нужно убрать анимацию при первом рендере, а не сделать так, чтобы она была всегда и при первом рендере.

Читать вопрос? А зачем? )) И так... Как должен работать хук и что такое первый рендер, если хук реагирует на смену url(роутер)? Этот хук стоит в каждом компоненте, который отрисовывается по тому или иному роуту или он стоит в родительском компоненте и при смете роутинга меняются его дочерние? От этого будет зависеть реализация. Добавьте в вопрос чуть больше кода, где будет видно, как хук используется в компонентах и где стоит роутинг

Роутинг в app.js, а hook я добавляю в каждую страницу в класс и все.

Вот вообще не понятно, что такое app.js и как в класс вы добавляете хук. Покажите кодом

Сейчас покажу, минуту

Обновил вопрос )

Так не получится. При смене роута, старый компонент будет размонтирован, а новый смонтирован(первый рендер) и старый забудет, что там что то вообще запускалось. Когда смените еще раз роут, для компонента это будет первый рендер. Проще передавать пропсами. Или в хуке обращаться к глобальному хранилищу и туда записывать - сколько раз вызывался

Капец! :( А как это через csstransition сделать? Там вроде же можно такое

Вам надо определить, что такое "первый рендер" с учетом того, что компонент не знает, сколько раз его монтировали. Эту информацию надо вам где то хранить в приложении и передавать компоненту, а уже на основе этих значених либо добавлять анимацию или нет.

Реакт в dev-режиме вызывает эффекты дважды - кажется, логика с isFirstRender.current при этом развалится?

Я щас прочитал про framer-motion, там вроде можно такое делать :)
